# Display multiple conversions of quantity in #ask query

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

Is it possible to display a Quantity in multiple units at the same time in `#ask` query.

Say I have a property `[[Has length]]`

```
[[Has type::Quantity]]
[[Display units::in,cm]]
[[Corresponds to::1 in]]
[[Corresponds to::2.54 cm]]
```

And then I have a query like

```
{{#ask: [Category:Cables]
|?Has length
|format=table
}}
```

I like to be able to display the length in 'in' and 'cm' say something like

```
Cable A | 12 in (30 cm)
Cable B | 6 in (15 cm)
```

I tried `|?Has length#in (cm)` but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Cables]]
|?Has length#in
|?Has length#cm
|format=table
}}
```

A similar example (length in meters and kilometers): https://traditio.wiki/Project:Test80.

Note the double brackets.

If you want to display different units of measurement in the same column, you have to use `format=template` and a corresponfing template like

```
{{!}}-
{{!}} {{{2|}}} ({{{3|}}})
```

Comment: Ah typo on the selection criteria - I didn't know you could use a template that looks like just what I want - I shall read docs. Thanks